# Clojure : Get "OutOfMemoryError Java heap space" when parsing big log file

Tags: clojure, out-of-memory

all.
I want to parse big log files using Clojure.
And the structure of each line record is "UserID,Lantitude,Lontitude,Timestamp".
My implemented steps are:
----> Read log file & Get top-n user list 
----> Find each top-n user's records and store in separate log file (UserID.log) .

The implement source code :

```
;======================================================
(defn parse-file
  ""
  [file n]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader file)]
    (println "001 begin with open ")
    (let [lines (line-seq rdr)
          res (parse-recur lines)
          sorted
          (into (sorted-map-by (fn [key1 key2]
                                 (compare [(get res key2) key2]
                                          [(get res key1) key1])))
                res)]
      (println "Statistic result : " res)
      (println "Top-N User List : " sorted)
      (find-write-recur lines sorted n)
      )))

(defn parse-recur
  ""
  [lines]
  (loop [ls  lines
         res {}]
    (if ls
      (recur (next ls)
               (update-res res (first ls))) 
      res)))

(defn update-res
  ""
  [res line]
  (let [params (string/split line #",")
        id     (if (> (count params) 1) (params 0) "0")]
    (if (res id)
      (update-in res [id] inc)
      (assoc res id 1))))

(defn find-write-recur
  "Get each users' records and store into separate log file"
  [lines sorted n]
  (loop [x n
         sd sorted
         id (first (keys sd))]
    (if (and (> x 0) sd)
      (do (create-write-file id
                             (find-recur lines id))
          (recur (dec x)
                 (rest sd)
                 (nth (keys sd) 1))))))

(defn find-recur
  ""
  [lines id]
  (loop [ls lines
           res []]
    (if ls
      (recur (next ls)
               (update-vec res id (first ls)))
      res)))

(defn update-vec
  ""
  [res id line]
  (let [params (string/split line #",")
        id_        (if (> (count params) 1) (params 0) "0")]
        (if (= id id_ )
          (conj res line)
          res)))

(defn create-write-file
  "Create a new file and write information into the file."
  ([file info-lines]
   (with-open [wr (io/writer (str MAIN-PATH file))]
     (doseq [line info-lines] (.write wr (str line "\n")))
     ))
  ([file info-lines append?]
   (with-open [wr (io/writer (str MAIN-PATH file) :append append?)]
     (doseq [line info-lines] (.write wr (str line "\n"))))
   ))
;======================================================
```

I tested this clj in REPL with command (parse-file "./DATA/log.log" 3), and get the results:

Records-----Size-----Time----Result 
1,000-------42KB-----<1s-----OK 
10,000------420KB----<1s-----OK
100,000-----4.3MB----3s------OK
1,000,000---43MB-----15s-----OK
6,000,000---258MB---->20M----"OutOfMemoryError Java heap space  java.lang.String.substring (String.java:1913)"

======================================================
Here is the question: 
1. how can i fix the error when i try to parse big log file , like > 200MB
2. how can i optimize the function to run faster ?
3. there are logs more than 1G size , how can the function deal with it.

I am still new to Clojure, any suggestion or solution will be appreciate~
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

As a direct answer to your questions; from a little Clojure experience.

1. The quick and dirty fix for running out of memory boils down to giving the JVM more memory. You can try adding this to your `project.clj`:

   ```
   :jvm-opts ["-Xmx1G"] ;; or more
   ```

   That will make Leiningen launch the JVM with a higher memory cap.
2. This kind of work is going to use a lot of memory no matter how you work it. @Vidya's suggestion ot use a library is definitely worth considering. However, there's one optimization that you *can* make that should help a little.

   Whenever you're dealing with your `(line-seq ...)` object (a lazy sequence) you should make sure to maintain it as a lazy seq. Doing `next` on it will pull the whole thing into memory at once.  Use `rest` instead. Take a look at the clojure site, especially the section on [laziness](http://clojure.org/lazy#Making%20Clojure%20Lazier--Enhancing%20the%20seq%20model%20-%20a%20third%20operation%20on%20seqs%20-%20%27next%27):

   > (**rest** aseq) - returns a possibly empty seq, never nil
   >
   > [snip]
   >
   > a (possibly) delayed path to the remaining items, if any

   You may even want to traverse the log twice--once to pull just the username from each line as a lazy-seq, again to filter out those users. This will minimize the amount of the file you're holding onto at any one time.
3. Making sure your function is lazy should reduce the sheer overhead that having the file as a sequence in memory creates. Whether that's enough to parse a 1G file, I don't think I can say.

Comment: I was thinking boosting the memory would just treat the symptom rather than cure the disease, but your point on *maintaining* laziness is great.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't need Cascalog or Hadoop simply to parse a file which doesn't fit into your Java heap.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118123/read-a-very-large-text-file-into-a-list-in-clojure/13312151#13312151) provides some working examples of how to process large files lazily.  The main point is you need to keep the file open while you traverse the lazy seq.  Here is what worked for me in a similar situation:

```
(defn lazy-file-lines [file]
  (letfn [(helper [rdr]
                  (lazy-seq
                    (if-let [line (.readLine rdr)]
                      (cons line (helper rdr))
                      (do (.close rdr) nil))))]
         (helper (clojure.java.io/reader file))))
```

You can `map`, `reduce`, `count`, etc. over this lazy sequence:

```
(count (lazy-file-lines "/tmp/massive-file.txt"))
;=> <a large integer>
```

The parsing is a separate, simpler problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am also relatively new to Clojure, so there are no obvious optimizations I can see. Hopefully others more experienced can offer some advice. But I feel like this is simply a matter of the data size being too big for the tools at hand.

For that reason, I would suggest using [Cascalog](https://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog), an abstraction over Hadoop or your local machine using Clojure. I think the syntax for querying big log files would be pretty straightforward for you.