# Clojure XML Stream Closed Exception

Tags: xml, clojure, xml-parsing

I am getting an exception parsing an XML file with `clojure.data.xml`, because the stream is closing before the parsing is complete.

What I do not understand is why `doall` is not forcing the evaluation of the XML data before `with-open` closes it (as suggested by [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10462159)):

```
(:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
          [clojure.data.xml :as xml])

(defn file->xml [path] 
  (with-open [rdr (-> path io/resource io/reader)] 
    (doall (xml/parse rdr))))
```

Which throws the exception:

```
(file->xml "example.xml")
;-> XMLStreamException ParseError at [row,col]:[80,1926]
Message: Stream closed com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next
```

If I remove the `with-open` wrapper, it returns the XML data as expected (so the file is legit though the reader is not guaranteed closed).

I see that `(source xml/parse)` yields lazy results:

```
(defn parse
  "Parses the source, which can be an
   InputStream or Reader, and returns a lazy tree of Element records. 
   Accepts key pairs with XMLInputFactory options, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html
   and xml-input-factory-props for more information. 
   Defaults coalescing true."
   [source & opts]
     (event-tree (event-seq source opts)))
```

so perhaps that is related, but the function I have is very similar to the "round-trip" example on the [clojure.data.xml README](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml#examples).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was surprised to see this behavior.  It appears that `clojure.data.xml.Element` (the return type) implements a type of "lazy map" that is immune to the effects of `doall`.

Here is a solution which transforms the lazy values into normal maps:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]]
    [clojure.java.io :as io]
    [clojure.data.xml :as xml]
    [clojure.walk :refer [postwalk]]
  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn unlazy
  [coll]
  (let [unlazy-item (fn [item]
                      (cond
                        (sequential? item) (vec item)
                        (map? item) (into {} item)
                        :else item))
        result    (postwalk unlazy-item coll) ]
    result ))

(defn file->xml [path]
  (with-open [rdr (-> path io/resource io/reader) ]
    (let [lazy-vals    (xml/parse rdr)
          eager-vals   (unlazy lazy-vals) ]
      eager-vals)))
(pprint (file->xml "books.xml"))

{:tag :catalog,
 :attrs {},
 :content
 [{:tag :book,
   :attrs {:id "bk101"},
   :content
   [{:tag :author, :attrs {}, :content ["Gambardella, Matthew"]}
    {:tag :title, :attrs {}, :content ["XML Developer's Guide"]}
    {:tag :genre, :attrs {}, :content ["Computer"]}
    {:tag :price, :attrs {}, :content ["44.95"]}
    {:tag :publish_date, :attrs {}, :content ["2000-10-01"]}
    {:tag :description,
     :attrs {},
     :content
     ["An in-depth look at creating applications\n      with XML."]}]}
  {:tag :book,
   :attrs {:id "bk102"},
   :content
   [{:tag :author, :attrs {}, :content ["Ralls, Kim"]}
    {:tag :title, :attrs {}, :content ["Midnight Rain"]}
    {:tag :genre, :attrs {}, :content ["Fantasy"]}
    {:tag :price, :attrs {}, :content ["5.95"]}
    {:tag :publish_date, :attrs {}, :content ["2000-12-16"]}
    {:tag :description,
     :attrs {},
     :content
     ["A former architect battles corporate zombies,\n      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen\n      of the world."]}]}
  {:tag :book,
   :attrs {:id "bk103"},
   :content .....
```

Since `clojure.data.xml.Element` implements `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap`, using `(map? item)` returns true.

Here is the [sample data for books.xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx)

## Please Note:

`clojure.data.xml` is different that `clojure.xml`.  You may need to explore both libraries to find the one that fits your needs best.

- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.xml
- https://github.com/clojure/data.xml

You can also use `crossclj.info` to find api docs when needed:

- https://crossclj.info/doc/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clojure.xml.html
- https://crossclj.info/doc/org.clojure/data.xml/0.2.0-alpha2/index.html

## Update:

Just a week or so after I saw this question I ran into an XML parsing problem just like this one that needed the `unlazy` function.  You can now find `unlazy` [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Thanks for the taking the time to clarify what is going on.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "immune" to doall; it rather seems as if it is another _level_ of lazy things, a lazy sequence of lazy sequences.

Comment: I haven't dug into the source code, but it appears that it is a "lazy map" type of structure, which is also seen with `datomic.query.EntityMap`. I think the problem is that `doall` is intended only for lazy sequences, not "lazy maps".