# get-in for lists

Tags: clojure

Apparently [`get-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in) doesn't work for `'()` lists since they're not an associative data structure. This makes sense for the API and from the perspective of performance of large lists. From my perspective as a user it'd be great to still use this function to explore some small test data in the repl. For example I want to be able to:

```
(-> '({:a ("zero" 0)} {:a ("one" 1)} {:a ("two" 2)})
     (get-in [1 :a 0]))

=> "one"
```

Is there some other function that works this way? Is there some other way to achieve this behavior that doesn't involve converting all my lists to (say) vectors?

Comment: Incidentally, SO wouldn't let me post this question until I upper-cased the G in `get-in` in the title. That seems like a bad feature...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you ask:

```
(defn get-nth-in [init ks]
  (reduce
    (fn [a k]
      (if (associative? a)
        (get a k)
        (nth a k)))
    init
    ks))
```

For example,

```
(-> '({:a "zero"} {:a "one"} {:a "two"})
     (get-nth-in [1 :a]))
;"one"
```

and

```
(-> '({:a ("zero" 0)} {:a ("one" 1)} {:a ("two" 2)})
     (get-nth-in [1 :a 0]))
;"one"
```

The extra `'`s you have get expanded into `(quote ...)`:

```
(-> '({:a '("zero" 0)} {:a '("one" 1)} {:a '("two" 2)})
     (get-nth-in [1 :a 0]))
;quote
```

Not what you intended, I think.

Comment: Yup! I screwed up the example, but this functionality is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[A post just yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194162/clojure-xml-stream-closed-exception) had a problem regarding lazy lists and lazy maps (from clojure/data.xml). One answer was to just replace the lazy bits with plain vectors & maps using this function:

```
(defn unlazy
  [coll]
  (let [unlazy-item (fn [item]
                      (cond
                        (sequential? item) (vec item)
                        (map? item) (into {} item)
                        :else item))
        result    (postwalk unlazy-item coll)
  ]
    result ))
```

Since the resulting data structure uses only vectors & maps, it works for your example with `get-in`:

```
 (let [l2  '({:a ("zero" 0)} {:a ("one" 1)} {:a ("two" 2)})
       e2  (unlazy l2) ]
      (is= l2 e2)
      (is= "one" (get-in e2 [1 :a 0] l2))
    )
```

You can find the `unlazy` function [in the Tupelo library.](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo)

Comment: In my particular case unlazying is quite time consuming, so for me the accepted answer is still preferable, but this is still a great function to keep around for a rainy day.

Answer (score -1):

The first param for get-in should be a map.

You have to figure out the feature of your sequence, use last, first, filter or some e.g. to get the element first

for example  you could use   `(:a  (last data))`

Comment: The first param doesn't need to be map, it can be a vector, for example. I updated my question to break your example solution.

Comment: That is why I said you have to figure out the feature of your sequence   if you are willing to use index  , do it like this   `(-> (vec '({:a "zero"} {:a "one"}))
    (get-in [1 :a]))`  However ,using index in vector  is not a perfect method